# CSS – Fixing edges after hovering on a rounded image

Tags: html, css

I've created `div` element, and I also added a `border-radius` attribute to make the `div` more aesthetically pleasing. I also added a `-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease` attribute to the `div` to create a transition to a dark overlay when the user hovers over the `div`. Then, I run into a problem which can be explained by these images.

Cursor outside the `div` element:

[image]

Moving the cursor inside the `div` element:
[image]

The cursor is fully inside the `div` element:
[image]

So, I guess this is a problem with the transition and it's caused by the rounded border of the image. It's kind of annoying and I'd like to remove it but I don't know how to. I've attached the code here:

Note: `.memX` (where X is a number) refers to each `div` element. There are like 10 `.mem` elements.

```
mem1, .mem2, .mem3, .mem4, .mem5, .mem6, .mem7, .mem8, .mem9, .mem10 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px 31px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: #d6d6d6;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 45px 0px 66px 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.insidetext {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.85);
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.mem1:hover .overlay, .mem2:hover .overlay, .mem3:hover .overlay, .mem4:hover .overlay, .mem5:hover .overlay, .mem6:hover .overlay, .mem7:hover .overlay, .mem8:hover .overlay, .mem9:hover .overlay {
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mem1 {
  background-image: url(members/giles.png);
}
```

This seems to be a problem in general. You can see this particular problem in action on this CodePen: http://codepen.io/ianfarb/pen/ikeAf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this..

```
body {
  background: #e7e7e7;
}

#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
  background: url(http://ianfarb.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/nicholas-hodag.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  text-align: center;
  /*padding: 45px 0 66px 0;*/
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

#box:hover #overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

#plus {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  font-size: 96px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLBqvE

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I'm confused as to why you've got so many `mem` classes. Class names can be reused, ID selectors cannot. So why have `.mem1` and so on when you could simply have `.mem`?

Anyway, to fix your problem all you need to do is add `border-radius:5px;` to `#overlay` and that should give you your desired effect.

Comment: My `border-radius` was 10px, not 5px. Also, I tried that and it removes the top two sharp edges, but not the bottom two.

Answer (score 0):

I your example you have two div one is parent (box) and another is chilled(overlay) and you apply border to parent and your hover effect is on chilled so when you hover it will apply  **transition** on chilled. and chilled has no **border-radius: 5px;** so apply   **border-radius: 5px;** to your chilled id also. so i think its an **overflow** issue

But you can try this soluttion:

solution is remove **delay** from **transition** then it works because of delay it will give you problem.

See this example for removed delay from transition :http://jsfiddle.net/9phk87x8/ **i think it will work for you.**

```
#overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 45px 0 66px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity ease;
}
```